# Android Studio lint showing "URI is not registered" in appengine-web.xml?

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

The default /webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml file for both "App Engine Java Serlet Module" and "App Engine Java Endpoint Module" contains this namespace:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
```

This namespace is flagged by lint with a "URI is not registered" message. It provides a pointer to Settings|Project Settings|Schemas and DTDs but the fix is not obvious.

[image]

This warning does not impact building or functionality of the module, but it feels wrong to just ignore it. How should this be fixed?

Comment: It must be a bug in the latest release of Android Studio. I have the same warning but the project works great for 6 months.

Answer (score 7):

Had this same problem just now, but I found a way to handle it.

Go to `Settings | Schemas and DTDs`

under `Ignored Schemas and DTDs`, copy the URI `http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0` and add it.

[image]

That's it, the warning disappears.

You can learn more about Schemas and DTDs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/schemas-and-dtds.html#d1088845e215)

Comment: Hmmmm. Just wondering why this was downvoted,since it is a valid answer to the question.

Comment: Nice workaround, but I'd prefer an approach that fixes the validation. Upvoting to offset the downvote. I agree that a downvote is inappropriate for a valid workaround.

Comment: I think it's a bug or something.The warning doesn't affect performance in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This just defines how the XML is structured, ignoring it doesn't really hurt you except that you wont get validation on your appengine-web.xml.

There is a manual fix for this:  You can point that url to `<appengine-sdk>/docs/appengine-web.xsd`. That can be annoying though, an automatic fix for this is being added as part of the cloud tooling in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks. However, when trying this I get a new warning: Cannot find the declaration of element 'appengine-web-app'. The app still works just fine.

Comment: On macOS I found the schema/dtd at: `~/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/docs` which worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using android studio / inellij - go to project structure >> facets >> click on the + sign on the top and add Google App Engine Standard

Alternatively, go to Project Structure >> modules >> click on the + sign on the top and add Google App Engine Standard

This should resolve the error from showing and also auto-populates the valid entries for code-completion.